# SugarCRM user password

Tags: sugarcrm

I've created a user in SugarCRM; once I've created a user the password is mailed to the user.
I see the table user, but the user_hash is blank.

Where does it store the password before it sends an email?

Comment: What happens if you try to login with the username/password sent in the email?. Sugar stores the password in the 'user_hash' column.

Answer (score 2):

Check the column 'system_generated_password'. 'user_hash' will be null until the new user logs in with the the system generated password and then creates a new password for themselves.

Comment: system_generated_password is a tinyint(1) so it's just a flag.

Answer (score 0):

I think you might be mistaken. I just created a new user with a user name `new_user`. I then did the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name = "new_user"
```

The `user_hash` has a value of `1e3fab09c625a96334d18d2da27dae46`.

I double-checked, and the password emailed to me was `l7YaR7`, which md5 hashes to the above.

I did this in Sugar 6.1.1. What version are you using?

Also, did the email get sent out? It's possible that the password hash isn't sent to the DB until after the email has been successfully sent.

Answer (score 0):

You can create user using md5 function if you using phpmyadmin.

You can alter the passworld and use md5() function;